# List vs. Dictionary (Maximum Size, Number of Elements)

Tags: c#, .net, list, c#-4.0, dictionary

I am attempting to ascertain the maximum sizes (in RAM) of a List and a Dictionary. I am also curious as to the maximum number of elements / entries each can hold, and their memory footprint per entry.

My reasons are simple: I, like most programmers, am somewhat lazy (this is a virtue). When I write a program, I like to write it once, and try to future-proof it as much as possible. I am currently writing a program that uses Lists, but noticed that the iterator wants an integer. Since the capabilities of my program are only limited by available memory / coding style, I'd like to write it so I can use a List with Int64s or possibly BigInts (as the iterators). I've seen IEnumerable as a possibility here, but would like to find out if I can just stuff a Int64 into a Dictionary object as the key, instead of rewriting everything. If I can, I'd like to know what the cost of that might be compared to rewriting it.

My hope is that should my program prove useful, I need only hit recompile in 5 years time to take advantage of the increase in memory.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Is it specified in the documentation for the class? No, then it's unspecified.

In terms of current implementations, there's no maximum size in RAM in the classes themselves, if you create a value type that's 2MB in size, push a few thousand into a list, and receive an out of memory exception, that's nothing to do with `List<T>`.

Internally, `List<T>`s workings would prevent it from ever having more than 2billion items. It's harder to come to a quick answer with `Dictionary<TKey, TValue>`, since the way things are positioned within it is more complicated, but really, if I was looking at dealing with a billion items (if a 32-bit value, for example, then 4GB), I'd be looking to store them in a database and retrieve them using data-access code.

At the very least, once you're dealing with a single data structure that's 4GB in size, rolling your own custom collection class no longer counts as reinventing the wheel.

Comment: Fair enough. I was curious, since the List iterator does not appear to like Int64s.

Comment: What do you mean by "doesn't like"?

Comment: List<Int64> parentnodes = new List<Int64>();

            for (Int64 i = 0; i < parentnodes.Count; i++)
            {
                Node n = parentnodes[i];


            }

Comment: It expects an int, and appears to only accept an int, not an Int64 for indexing.

Comment: So does `List<string>`. The indexer is nothing to do with a dislike for types.

Answer (score 3):

I am using a concurrentdictionary to rank 3x3 patterns in half a million games of go. Obviously there are a lot of possible patterns. With C# 4.0 the concurrentdictionary goes out of memory at around 120 million objects. It is using 8GB at that time (on a 32GB machine) but wants to grow way too much I think (tablegrowths happen in large chunks with concurrentdictionary). Using a database would slow me down at least a hundredfold I think. And the process is taking 10 hours already.

My solution was to use a multiphase solution, actually doing multiple passes, one for each subset of patterns. Like one pass for odd patterns and one for even patterns. When using more objects no longer fails I can reduce the amount of passes.

C# 4.5 adds support for larger arraysin 64bit by using unsigned 32bit pointers for arrays
(the mentioned limit goes from 2 billion to 4 billion). See also
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh285054(v=vs.110).aspx. Not sure which objects will benefit from this, List<> might.

Answer (score 2):

I think you have bigger issues to solve before even wondering if a `Dictionary` with an `int64` key will be useful in 5 or 10 years.

Having a `List` or `Dictionary` of 2e+10 elements in memory (`int32`) doesn't seem to be a good idea, never mind 9e+18 elements (`int64`). Anyhow the framework will never allow you to create a monster that size (not even close) and probably never will. (Keep in mind that a simple `int[int.MaxValue]` array already far exceeds the framework's limit for memory allocation of any given object).

And the question remains: Why would you ever want your application to hold in memory a list of so many items? You are better of using a specialized data storage backend (database) if you have to manage that amount of information.

Comment: Dealing with extremely large trees. And a database, at this size, would actually be slower than the method I have in mind. Still, my point was to write the code so that it would not require reworking later, as memory sizes are still growing (last I checked).

Comment: "Keep in mind that a simple int[int.MaxValue] array already far exceeds the framework's limit for memory allocation of any given object)." You actually mean the size the keys will take in the dictionary, not the objects it will hold, right?

Comment: @Marco: Keys and objects both. They have to exist somewhere in memory, and you just can not allocate that much memory. The fact that the dictionary holds a reference to the object and not the object itself doesn't help in any way.

Comment: @InBetween definitely something wrong to do, as for the clr memory allocation limit: http://blogs.msdn.com/b/joshwil/archive/2005/08/10/450202.aspx. You cannot say for certain that int[int.MaxValue] exceeds the limit of the memory allocation, I believe.

Comment: In my many years of program, I have had to build many applications where I wish to store as much in memory as possible, usually for reasons of speed. A database access (if disk based) is orders of magnitude slower. Large sparse matrices, transportation problems, large discrete simulation models, etc. are just of few examples of these.