# Is this O(1) when I use the hashset?

Tags: c#

I have a `HashSet` of a type:

```
public Class Person
{
    int? _requestedHashCode;
    long Id;
    Name string;
    DateTime BirthDate;
    // Other properties


    public bool IsTransient()
    {
        return this.Id == default(long);
    }


    public override int GetHashCode()
    {
        if (!IsTransient())
        {
            if (!_requestedHashCode.HasValue)
                _requestedHashCode = this.Id.GetHashCode() ^ 31;

            return _requestedHashCode.Value;
        }
        else
            return base.GetHashCode();
    }


    public override bool Equals(object obj)
    {
        if (obj == null || !(obj is Person))
            return false;

        if (Object.ReferenceEquals(this, obj))
            return true;

        if (this.GetType() != obj.GetType())
            return false;

        Entity item = (Entity)obj;

        if (item.IsTransient() || this.IsTransient())
            return false;
        else
            return item.Id == this.Id;
    }
}
```

I have a method that receives as parameter the ID of the person, and I would like to get the person with O(1) performance:

```
public Person GetPerson(long paramIdPersonToDelete)
{
    return _myHashset.FirstOrDefault(x => x.Id == paramIdPersonToDelete);
}
```

Is my implementation correct? I am not sure what I need to modify; the comparison that needs the `HashSet`, if the `HashSet` uses `GetHashCode()`, or `Equals()` or both.

Thanks.

Comment: `FirstOrDefault` is always O(n), you are enumerating the HashSet

Comment: No. You should use a Dictionary for this. Not a Hashset.

Comment: `FirstOrDefault(x => x.Id == paramIdPersonToDelete)` is not an O(1) operation. This will iterate through the HashSet till it finds a **Person** with the matching **Id**.

In your case it would make more sense to use a `Dictionary`. You could format it like this: `Dictionary<long, Person>`.

Comment: Side note: I highly doubt the extra cost of the `if (!_requestedHashCode.HasValue)` is worth it. Just change the whole GetHashcode to `return this.Id.GetHashCode() ^ 31;`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`First` or `FirstOrDefault` are LINQ methods(so not optimized for `HashSet<T>`) that need to enumerate the sequence to find an item. That means they have `O(n)` complexity.

If you want `O(1)` you could use this approach:

```
public Person GetPerson(long paramIdPersonToDelete)
{
    return _myHashset.TryGetValue(new Person{ Id = paramIdPersonToDelete }, out Person actualPerson)
        ? actualPerson
        : null;
}
```

Of course you need to make `Id` public or - better - provide a constructor and make it `readonly`.

In this case it would be better to use a `Dictionary<long, Person>`.

Comment: The reason I asked it is, if I create the person setting only the Id, the rest of the properties has the default values. If I have many properties with different ID and the rest of properties with the default values, is it enough to have different ID to be O(1)?

Comment: @ÁlvaroGarcía: Yes, that's why it might be better to use a `Dictionary<long, Person>` if you want a mapping between the Id and a Person. Your hashcode/equals logic seems to be more complex than simply comparing the `Id`.

Comment: @Alvaro This might help to answer that question: [What does it mean when an operation "approaches O(1)" as opposed to "is O(1)"?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19989075/what-does-it-mean-when-an-operation-approaches-o1-as-opposed-to-is-o1)